# How do I "reduce" a Prolog list of pairs?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to do some graph analysis using PROLOG. In particular I want a list of pairs which indicate the number of nodes at each deeper level from the root. I'm able to produce a list of pairs of the form:

```
M = [1-[431, 441, 443, 444, 445, 447, 449], 2-[3, 5, 7, 8, 409, 451|...]].
```

The pair key is the graph level; the pair value is the list of nodes at that level;
whereas I want the pair value to be a count of the nodes.
But I can't figure out to reduce `M` to `N`.

```
N = [1-7],[2,20,],...........[8-398]
```

where `N` indicates 7 nodes at the 1th level etc....    perhaps I need a good set of examples working with pairs.
Simpler data could be `M=[1-[a,b,c],],2-[d,e]]` should reduce to `N=[1-3,2-2]`  Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to map a list of such pairs to another list element-wise as follows

```
list_bylength(KLs, KNs) :-
   maplist(el_len, KLs, KNs).

el_len(I-L,I-N) :-
   length(L, N).
```

Alternatively:

```
list_bylength2([], []).
list_bylength2([I-L|ILs], [I-N|INs]) :-
   length(L, N),
   list_bylength2(ILs, INs).
```

And most compactly, using [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord):

```
..., maplist(\ (I-L)^(I-N)^length(L,N), ILs, INs), ...
```

Comment: That worked like a charm.  My full expresion:
gencnts(I,LevelCounts) :-findall(T-Y,(ancecnt(I,Y,0,T,13)),F),
  sort(F,L),group_pairs_by_key(L,M),
  list_bylength(M,LevelCounts).

It summarized 7 generations of ancestry to:
[1-7, 2-43, 3-56, 4-87, 5-110, 6-80, 7-15]

Answer (score 0):

a lot of list processing can be performed by findall/3, using member/2 as 'cursor'.

```
list_bylength(KLs, KNs) :-
  findall(K-L, (member(K-Ls,KLs),length(Ls,L)), KNs).
```